# MongooseError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "example" at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I had this problem for few days and I can't seem to fix the problem.

I have searched on google and lot of people suggested that I need to downgrade mongoose and mongodb because new updates has been creating the problem.

downgrade both of them but didn't work.

**This is my schema:**

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");

    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       username: String,
       email: String,
       password: String,
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema, "user");
```

**This is my server.js:**

```
app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.id,"hi")
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, me){
        if(err){
            console.log(err,"not working")
        } else {
            // var me = {username: req.params.id}
            console.log(me, "hello")
            res.send(me)
        }
    })
})
```

as result I get

```
example hi 
MongooseError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "example" at path "_id" at CastError
```

in my server.

It seem like it's finding req.params.id because 'example' is the user's username but I do not understand why such a problem is occurring.

Please share you insights!

Comment: Try `User.findOne({"username":req.params.id}, function(err, me){..}`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!